# Python: Unit Testing Module and Relative Imports

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-packaging

Currently have the following file hierarchy:

```
\package
    __init__.py
    run_everything.py

    \subpackage
        __init__.py
        work.py
        work1.py
        work2.py

    \test
        __init__.py
        test_work.py
        test_work1.py
```

My first question is regarding relative imports. Suppose in \subpackage\work.py I have a function called custom_function(), and I would like to test that function in test_work.py. For some reason I can not figure out how to make this import from one module to another. Trying `from .. subpackage.work1 import custom_function()` does not seem to work, and yields the error `Attempted relative import in non-package` Is there any way to resolve this?

2)
I would like to run all test files from run_everything.py with one function, would adding a suite() function in each test_work*.py file, which adds each unit_testing class to suite.addTest(unittest.makeSuite(TestClass)), and finally importing them into the top-level run_everything.py be the most *conventional way* in Python2.7?

Comment: I highly recommend not using relative imports, especially in tests.

Comment: so where would they go? placing the test module in the subpackage would force the same import statements no?

Comment: Typically you wouldn't put the tests in the package at all, but instead in a separate directory tree.

Comment: If its a long running project, after a while it becomes messy with the relative imports (especially if you want to refactor)... Its always better to have full package paths and make sure your top package is in the  PYTHONPATH

Answer (score 1):

Here is a hack* 
Insert the path's to "subpackage" and "test" to your python path in run_everything using:

```
    import sys
    sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/package/subpackage')
    sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/package/test')
```

And then, you can import all your files using vanilla imports in run_everything:

```
    import work, work1, work2
    import test_work, test_work1
```

*This won't permanently affect your PYTHONPATH.

Comment: A lot of people prefer to put the new path at the start of `PYTHONPATH`, e.g. `sys.insert(0, '/path/to/pkg')` that way if the package is also installed into site-packages your tests will import the version of the modules from `/path/to/`.

Comment: I think you mean `sys.path.insert(0,'/path/to/pkg')`

Comment: @snim2 mportant observations! Updated Answer to reflect.